# Handling data without ground truth bounding boxes in SSD / RetinaNet?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, computer-vision, object-detection

In the paper [*SSD: Single Shot MultiBox Detector* by Liu *et al.*, 2015](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02325), the `Matching strategy` section reads:

> During training we need to determine which default boxes correspond
>   to a ground truth detection and train the network accordingly.

Now, suppose we have some cases in our data which do not have any object in the image (hence, no ground truth bounding boxes). How do we handle this situation during training?

Comment: Machine learning models which can learn from both labeled and un-labeled data is [tag:semi-supervised] learning.

Comment: @Sycorax As I understand the question, it does not regard unlabeled data, rather data which are *correctly labeled* as having no objects in them. I removed the [semi-supervised] tag and returned conv-net again, as both referenced network architectures are conv-nets.

Answer (score 5):

**You need to remove those images from the training set.**

Since these networks work in supervised fashion, presenting them with images without any bounding boxes would either have no effect (just wasting the computational time), or even be inferior to the performance (since you would be learning the network to NOT predict anything even if there were real objects in the image).

Comment: At test time, I may get images without any objects in them. Don't you think I should train the model to generalize well for such cases too?

Comment: I assume in the rest of the training data there are images which have objects in part of the area and nothing in the rest, right? Then the network is learning to predict objects where they are, and predict nothing everywhere else. It only takes the content into account - there is no need to explicitly tell the network that images without objects may also happen. Unless you struggle with false positives, I would leave these out. Note that some open implementations of SSD will not work if there are no bounding boxes in a training image.